# AjaxCalendar Extender not showing Saturdays in Chrome, Firefox or Safari

Tags: c#, google-chrome, firefox, safari, calendarextender

Having a bit of trouble with the CalendarExtender here on a project. Basically, it's not showing Saturdays in Chrome, Firefox or Safari, but shows them perfectly in IE. Obviously, this is a bit of a problem.

I've tried stuffing around with the CSS to no avail, and so I come here for help! The Saturday's are there, but they're not showing, like this picture (due to my newness, I'm not allowed to post images directly!):

http://i.neoseeker.com/mgv/385085/85/87/calendarerror_display.png

Hopefully you can make it out in the picture, but I actually do have Saturday selected, as confirmed by the popup, but it's useless as it is.

Here is the code, hopefully this can give some insight in to what I'm doing wrong D:

```
<div id="left">
<h1>FIND EVENT</h1>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFind" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="txt" OnTextChanged="txtFind_TextChanged" Width="175px" ForeColor="#999999">Click to Find Date</asp:TextBox>  
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="calFindDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFind" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"></asp:CalendarExtender> 
<br />
<asp:ListBox ID="lstbxFind" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="390px"     Width="182px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstbxFind_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
<br />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnNew" runat="server" CssClass="lnk" OnClick="lnkbtnNew_Click">New</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="lnk" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this fixture event?')"                              onclick="lnkbtnDelete_Click">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
 <div id="email" runat="server" class="confirm">Event Saved</div>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnSave" runat="server" CssClass="lnk" OnClick="lnkbtnSave_Click" ValidationGroup="Group1">Save</asp:LinkButton>
 <br />  
 <br />
 <!-- <br />       
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#F6F6F6" Text="Label"></asp:Label>-->
 </div>
```

Hopefully this makes sense to someone and can at least point me in the right direction. I'm quite new to C# and whatnot, so I am certainly learning on the job here! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have css rule with `max-width` specified for children of `left` div?

Comment: No I don't. I have a `width` measurement, but not a `max-width`.